# Part of screen blank/fuzzy on start up

Tags: screen

As mentioned in the title, part of the screen is blank/fuzzy on start up:

[image: ([see picture here][1]).]

However I can still see the mouse and when I suspend the machine then wake it up, I can see the login screen and everything is fine.

It doesn't make sense that it would be a problem with the hardware as it worked fine before with windows installed and it only happens when I first turn the machine on.  I've tried installing fresh copies of both Ubuntu and Lubuntu.

Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. Its a bug in the Linux 4.13 kernel that's used in that version of ubuntu. All derived distros of ubuntu for the 17.04 n 17.10 version uses a version of the Linux kernel that has a bug for the Intel mobile 945 graphics. A temp fix is suspend the machine and move the mouse and press enter and the screen will come back to normal. Or just upgrade your ubuntu or variant to 18.04 and above which uses the updated Linux kernel that fixed the bug.

The bug is well known
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1724639

Upgrading to Lubuntu 18.10 LTS solved the problem because it uses the updated kernel. My screen looked exactly the same at the pic on top and that's how I fixed it.